# python unable to install python-telegram-bot `Searching for certifi` error

Tags: python, installation, setup.py, python-telegram-bot

I tried to install `python-telegram-bot` using [the instructions found here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-telegram-bot#installing).

When I run `python setup.py install` I get error given below:

```
creating 'dist/python_telegram_bot-5.2.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing python_telegram_bot-5.2.0-py2.7.egg
Copying python_telegram_bot-5.2.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding python-telegram-bot 5.2.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-5.2.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for python-telegram-bot==5.2.0
Searching for certifi
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'certifi' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for certifi
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('certifi')
```

I can reach the Internet over the network proxy, I can `wget` or `git` works fine. I have setup environment network proxy username, password variables in `.bashrc`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check if this file is available n downloadable through browser.fileshttps://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi

Comment: Did you set both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables?

Comment: @Gerrat Yes, as I said, I can download from http/https sites using wget.

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi Yes, it shows a list of `tar.gz` and `whl` files.

Comment: Does `sudo -E python setup.py install` work?

Comment: `sudo -E python setup.py install` is also not working. I am getting error `Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required -- Some packages may not be found!`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, "Couldn't find index page for 'certifi'",  when I tried to install the Matplotlib tool. My solution was installing the Certifi tool by `pip install certifi`.

My runtime environment:
  OS: Ubuntu 16.04
  Python 3.6
  Hardware: Nvidia TX2